# Differentiate multiple instances of NetBeans by customizing the title of the window

Tags: netbeans, title

Using `--userdir` and `--cachedir` options when launching NetBeans makes it possible to launch multiple independent instances.

However, I didn't find a way to **customize the title of the window of each instance** to be able **to differentiate them easily**. For now I gave them a different icon, but it's not enough.